# ActiveWeb : custom controllers in sub-packages do not work

Tags: javalite, activeweb

I created a `RouteConfig` class in `app.config` package as follows:

```
public class RouteConfig extends AbstractRouteConfig {
  @Override
  public void init(AppContext appContext) {

  route("/{controller}/{aut_id}/").to(AuthorsController.class).action("findById");
}
```

I created `AppControllerConfig` class:

```
package app.config;

import app.controllers.CatchAllFilter;
import app.controllers.api.v2.AuthorsController;
import org.javalite.activeweb.AbstractControllerConfig;
import org.javalite.activeweb.AppContext;
import org.javalite.activeweb.controller_filters.DBConnectionFilter;

public class AppControllerConfig extends AbstractControllerConfig {

    public void init(AppContext context) {
        add(new DBConnectionFilter(), new CatchAllFilter()).to(AuthorsController.class);
    }
}
```

I also defined `APIController` class as follows:

```
package app.controllers;

import org.javalite.activeweb.AppController;

public abstract class APIController extends AppController {
    @Override
    protected String getContentType() {
        return "application/json";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getLayout() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

`AuthorsController` is in `app.controllers.api.v2` package:

```
import app.controllers.APIController;

import app.models.Author;

public class AuthorsController extends APIController {

    public void findById() {
        if (blank("aut_id")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("aut_id number is mandatory but was empty or null");
        } else {
            Author author = Author.findById(param("aut_id"));
            String jsonResponse = author.toJson(false);
            respond(jsonResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to access the url `http://localhost:8080/api/v2/authors/9`, I'm getting the error:

```
Request properties: Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/v2/authors/9
ContextPath: 
Query String: null
URI Full Path: /api/v2/authors/9
URI Path: /api/v2/authors/9
Method: GET

Request parameters: {}
Request headers: {Cookie=_ga=GA1.1.1833610632.1527846931; JSESSIONID=node03k88mhw4nihozrzi9ehiiadj0.node0, Cache-Control=no-cache, Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8, Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=1, Connection=keep-alive, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36, Host=localhost:8080, Pragma=no-cache, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, Accept-Language=en,fr;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8}
org.javalite.activeweb.ActionNotFoundException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: app.controllers.api.v2.AuthorsController.9(); app.controllers.api.v2.AuthorsController.9()
[qtp1987707214-16] WARN ParamCopy - found 'session' value set by controller. It is reserved by ActiveWeb and will be overwritten.
[qtp1987707214-16] INFO FreeMarkerTemplateManager - rendering template: '/system/404' with layout: '/layouts/default_layout', session: node018slc2f7n5p0v67173ezr8guc0
[qtp1987707214-16] WARN FreeMarkerTemplateManager - Current location: /Users/Serguei/projects/java/newton-interventions
[qtp1987707214-16] ERROR RequestDispatcher - ActiveWeb internal error: 
org.javalite.activeweb.ViewMissingException: Failed to render template: '/system/404.ftl', with layout: '/layouts/default_layout'; Template "/system/404.ftl" not found.
```

What am I doing wrong ? I don't even enter the `AuthorsController`...
It seems like it ignores my route definition and tries to find the following one:

```
"method":"GET","action":"9","error":"java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: app.controllers.api.v2.AuthorsController.9()
```

When declaring `index` action in the same controller as follows:

```
public void index() {
        final String json = Author.findFirst("AUT_ID = 9").toJson(false);
        respond(json);
    }
```

and hitting `http://localhost:8080/api/v2/authors`, it works.

Answer (score 1):

This flushed a bug in the routing system: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb/issues/397
The bug was fixed and a new snapshot deployed to Sonatype version: 2.3-SNAPSHOT. 
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/javalite/activeweb/2.3-SNAPSHOT/

You can now try to see if this works. BWT, thanks for a detailed description, it helped to setup the right spec:  [RouterCustomSpec](https://github.com/javalite/activeweb/blob/master/activeweb/src/test/java/org/javalite/activeweb/RouterCustomSpec.java#L299)

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks a lot, - glad my issue to be helpful in framework improvement. I'll take a look at the new snapshot release.

Comment: Any tips on how to replace the previous dependency in `pom.xml` by the `2.3-SNAPSHOT`? When modifying it as `<version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>`, it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Please, follow instructions here http://javalite.io/releases#current-snapshot-2.3-snapshot

Comment: I tried 2.3-snapshot and it fails again. Here is my route definition in `RouteConfig`: `route("/{controller}/invoiceNumber/{invoiceNumber}").to(InterventionsController.class).action("findByInvoiceNumber");`. Here is the logs: `INFO org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher - {"info":"executing controller","controller":"app.controllers.api.v2.InterventionsController","action":"invoiceNumber","method":"GET"}`. As you see, the called action is wrong, - instead of `findByInvoiceNumber`, it looked for `invoiceNumber`: `Processed ..., path: /api/v2/interventions/invoiceNumber/316`.

Comment: I put more detailed information in the [issue](https://github.com/javalite/activeweb/issues/397) you closed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out how to make it work.

I changed the route declaration in `RouteConfig` class as follows:

```
route("/{controller}/find-by-id}/{id}").to(AuthorsController.class).action("findById");
```

I changed`findById` mehtod in `AuthorsController` as follows:

```
public void findById() {
        System.out.println(params());
        if (blank("id")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("autId number is mandatory but was empty or null");
        } else {
            Author author = Author.findById(param("id"));
            String jsonResponse = author.toJson(false);
            respond(jsonResponse);
        }
    }
```

It seems like by convention, the name of parameter passed in as a number to the url is considered as to be `id` and nothing else, right ?

Comment: this is not accurate. An `id` can be anything, string, number, etc.